# I have a problem in "Look + preposition" Rule

Tags: prepositions

I have a problem in deciding preposition

Sentence A :

> She's looking at me,

I want to change "me" with "here" , the sentence became :

> "She's looking at here"

1. Please correct the sentence above (at least what would a native english speaker use for this sentence)
2. Please give me guide about "Look + Preposition"

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. This question is not really on topic here, please read our [about] page. You may be interested in our companion site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suited to [ell.se]

Answer (score 2):

The sentence above should be "She is looking there"

Verb "look" has many prepositions but the most popular are "to", "at", "for", "after".

Examples:

- She is looking to the right. (to is for right, left,etc.)
- She is looking at the sunset. (at is for a person, an object.)
- She is looking for her brother. (this is similar to search.)
- She is looking after her mother. (it is much different than these three sentences it is not even associated with eyes but with care)

In summary verbs have many prepositions but they are not all similar in meaning.